# Inserting another query inside of sql script using string format with psycopg2

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to drop a table and recreate it from another query. I need to do this multiple times so I am using python script to automate it. Code is as follows;

```py
sql_template = """

DROP TABLE {table_name};

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {table_name} AS 
(
    {another_query}
)

WITH (
    OIDS = False
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;
"""

with open("query.sql", "r") as f:
    query = f.read()

sql = sql_template.format(table_name = "people", another_query=query)

pgCur.execute(sql)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

SyntaxError                               Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-6-95d24e664779> in <module>

----> 1 pgCur.execute(sql)

 

SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "("

LINE 430: WITH (

               ^
```

sql statement prints the following `print(sql)`:

```
DROP TABLE people;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS people AS 
(
    select * from customers c 
where c.order_compleate = TRUE
)

WITH (
    OIDS = False
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

Comment: Your Python code builds an SQL statement that is sent to the database. Get that statement, and you probably have the answer.

Comment: 1) `WITH (OIDS = False)` is not needed in Postgres 12+ as `oids` are not created with tables anymore. 2) Look at [CREATE TABLE AS](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtableas.html) and you will see the `WITH` goes before the query.

Comment: I should have clearer, since Postgres 12 it is not possible to create a table with `oids` at all. Since Postgres 8.1 the `default_with_oids` configuration setting was `off` by default so creating a table did not add the `oid` column unless you had changed the conf setting or explicitly requested `WITH OIDS`.

Comment: deleting after that part worked but, Could you please explain why `WITH` was going before the other argument?

Comment: Because that is the syntax as described in [CREATE TABLE AS](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtableas.html)